# Intel modular server - blinking yellow led - clear,confirm the warning

Tags: memory, vmware-esx, intel, blade-server

Masters,

Today we got tow warning from intel modular server, as you see below.

How to clear this warning and how to stop warning led blinking? (i'm sure there is no problem, but can't clear/confirm the warning.)

Thank you !

```
Host Name: cbcmm
IP Address: 192.168.1.207
Date: 3/30/2016
Time: 0:23:09
Event Id: 2925
Policy Id: 2070
Severity: Warning
Type: Chassis
Component: Server 2
User Name: System
Description: Memory Error: Correctable ECC error with bank DIMM_F2. These are errors that occur in memory cells but are corrected by the chipset ECC engine.

Probable Cause: Affected memory bank DIMM_F2.
Corrective Action: Monitor the condition and replace the memory when necessary.
Extra Data: s:68:"Raw IPMI (hex): Gen:3200 Num:02 Type:0c EDir:6f ED1:a0
ED2:00 ED3:31";
Host Name: cbcmm
IP Address: 192.168.1.207
Date: 3/30/2016
Time: 0:23:31
Event Id: 2927
Policy Id: 1602
Severity: Warning
Type: Chassis
Component: Chassis
User Name: System
Description: Sensor: Fault Indication; The Chassis Fault LED has been illuminated. This amber LED is located on the front of the chassis and is used to warn of conditions that require attention.

Probable Cause: Chassis Sensor: Fault Indication
Corrective Action: Check the events report for other warning or critical events that may be contributing to the chassis fault. Take appropriate action to clear those events and the fault LED will be turned off.

Extra Data: s:68:"Raw IPMI (hex): Gen:2000 Num:5b Type:c0 EDir:6f ED1:01 ED2:ff ED3:ff";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally replace the DIMM in slot F2/2 - but if you're not too worried about it then perhaps a full power-off and restart could clear the error - I'd still want to replace the DIMM though.

Comment: so there is no option to clear/accept the warning and stop blinkin' during operation via control panel?